# dnsmasq & systemd Causing Intermittent CPU Spikes

Tags: ubuntu, dnsmasq, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

## Problem:

**Running Ubuntu 17.10**

I have been trying to resolv (hehe) this issue for about a week now and despite countless Google searches and about 20 different attempts, I can not stop dnsmasq from periodically causing my CPU to spike for about a minute with the following offenders:

- `systemd-resolved`
- `systemd-journald`
- `dnsmasq`

Monitoring `journalctl -f` I see this every time it happens:

> maximum number of concurrent dns queries reached (150)

Accompanied/preceded by a crazy loop of requests to some domain (usually ubuntu connection check) like the following:

```
query[A] connectivity-check.ubuntu.com from 127.0.0.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.1.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.0.53
query[A] connectivity-check.ubuntu.com from 127.0.0.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.0.53
query[AAAA] connectivity-check.ubuntu.com from 127.0.0.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.0.53
query[AAAA] connectivity-check.ubuntu.com from 127.0.0.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.0.53
query[A] connectivity-check.ubuntu.com from 127.0.0.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.0.53
query[AAAA] connectivity-check.ubuntu.com from 127.0.0.1
forwarded connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to 127.0.0.53
```

I've found that changing my **/etc/resolv.conf** to use `nameserver 127.0.0.53` causes the spike to dissipate almost instantaneously.

However, as that file is updated regularly by Network Manager, I have to do this about once an hour.

---

## Configuration:

#### /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search fios-router.home
```

#### /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

#### /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
// All default except this at the very end for my wildcard DNS
address=/asmar.d/127.0.0.1
```

#### /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

#### /run/resolvconf/interfaces:

**`lo.dnsmasq`:**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

**`systemd-resolved`:**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

#### /etc/resolvconf/interface-order:

```
# interface-order(5)
lo.inet6
lo.inet
lo.@(dnsmasq|pdnsd)
lo.!(pdns|pdns-recursor)
lo
tun*
tap*
hso*
em+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
p+([0-9])p+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
@(br|eth)*([^.]).inet6
@(br|eth)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(br|eth)*([^.]).inet
@(br|eth)*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(br|eth)*
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet6
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*
ppp*
*
```

#### `systemd-resolve --status`:

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 5 (br-b1f5461ac410)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 4 (docker0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 3 (wlp62s0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (enp61s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
                      ::1
```

---

## Questions:

> How can I resolve this issue while still using my wildcard domain name?
>
> **Optional**: How can I achieve this while using Google DNS?

***Please do not recommend upping the concurrent dns queries. That is not a solution.***

---

## SOLVED!

#### [See telcoM's DNS crash course (the accepted answer) that led me to the solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418180/265441)

#### [See my follow-up & final solution as I experimented with the knowledge gained from that answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418211/265441)

Comment: do you have any evidence to suggest that it's caused by the existence of a wildcard?   does the same thing happen if you comment out your wildcard host?  or change it to a non-wildcard?

Comment: Not necessarily -- I do have evidence that it's caused by dnsmasq (this doesn't happen if I remove it), however. Which is the only way I know of (though I'm sure there are more) to implement a wildcard domain name in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may have `dnsmasq` process in 127.0.0.1 and `systemd-resolved` process in 127.0.0.53 passing queries back and forth between each other, causing a loop. Even `dnsmasq` alone might be capable of looping, as by default it looks into `/etc/resolv.conf` to find the real DNS servers to use for the names it does not have information for.

Your DNS configuration probably has quite many layers:

- first, there is the DNS server information you get from your ISP by DHCP or similar.
- then, there is `NetworkManager`, which could be configured to override the information and use `dnsmasq` instead, but isn't currently configured that way.
- instead, `NetworkManager` is configured to use the `resolvconf` tool to update the real `/etc/resolv.conf`. And `dnsmasq` may include a drop-in configuration for `resolvconf` to override any DNS services received by DHCP and use 127.0.0.1 instead while `dnsmasq` is running.
- systemd-resolved may also include a drop-in configuration for `resolvconf`, but is apparently getting overridden by `dnsmasq`.

What I don't yet understand is where the 127.0.1.1 and 127.0.0.53 come from. Are they perhaps mentioned in `dnsmasq` default configuration in Ubuntu?

As it says in the comment of `/etc/resolv.conf`, run this command to see more information on `systemd-resolved` configuration:

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

Also check the contents of the `/run/resolvconf/interface/` directory: that is where the `resolvconf` tool collects all the DNS server information it gets from various sources. The `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order` will determine the order in which each source is checked, until either a loopback address is encountered or 3 DNS servers have been listed for real `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Since you are using `dnsmasq` to set up a wildcard domain, you'll want to keep `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` - but you'll want to configure `dnsmasq` to not use that file, but instead get the DNS servers it should use from somewhere else.

If `/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf` contains those DNS servers you get from your ISP by DHCP, you can easily use that for `dnsmasq` by adding this line to its configuration:

```
resolv-file=/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

This tells `dnsmasq` where to get DNS information for those things it don't already know about. So if you want to use Google DNS, you could configure `dnsmasq` with

```
resolv-file=/etc/google-dns-resolv.conf
```

and put the DNS configuration lines for Google DNS in the usual format to `/etc/google-dns-resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I'm testing a solution based on your recommendations and updating my question accordingly with additional detail (adding a "Follow-up" section). The changes I've made seemed to make a difference which I'll describe above. I'm going to run things for a little bit to see how it behaves over time (since this has been an intermittent issue). If everything checks out, the bounty is absolutely yours!

Comment: Still experiencing CPU spikes - the difference I noticed initially was just misinterpreted. I've added as much detail regarding all of this in the **Folllow-up** section above.

Comment: Also -- I discovered that when I restart `dnsmasq`, `journalctl -f` shows me "**no servers found in /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf, will retry**". So, I decided to see what the contents of that file were and it is `nameserver 127.0.0.53`.

Comment: Preliminary update: I've replaced the contents of **/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf** with `nameserver 127.0.0.1` and the output of `journalctl -f` only shows `127.0.0.1` now. No CPU spiking since doing it and wildcard DNS is still functioning. I will update after I've let it run like this for a little bit.

Comment: With the info here, I was able to solve this issue! Please see "Update #3" in my question above for more detail. Bounty will be available in 15 hours at which point I will award it to you. Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: I've actually moved my follow-up and updates into an answer for clarity. Feel free to migrate any of the findings from there into your answer if you'd prefer.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1670959/comments/51

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my dnsmasq systemd-resolve race with dnsmasq config.

1. Use systemd-resolve (127.0.0.53) for external dns, as it does dnssec and has root servers.
2. Only bind dnsmasq to loopback for some static configs, could add more interfaces if i need it for dhcp.

/etc/dnsmasq.d/myconfig

```
#PES 20180808 dnsmasq and systemd-resolve conflict.
# dont use /etc/resolv.conf, go direct to systemd-resolve, only bind to lo
no-resolv
bind-interfaces
interface=lo
server=127.0.0.53
```

Answer (score 1):

## On Ubuntu 18.04

### 1 - Create /etc/google-dns-resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

### 2 - Create a config file /etc/dnsmasq.d/my_dnsmaq.conf

```
resolv-file=/etc/google-dns-resolv.conf
```

### 3 - Insert at the bottom of /etc/default/dnsmasq

```
IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes
```

### 4 - Finally, restart your dnsmasq service

`sudo service dnsmasq restart`

---

I've used [Johny's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/265441/jonny-asmar) above but step nº3 in my answer was missing in order for my dnsmasq config file to be read properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I originally documented this as a part of the question as I was trying
>   various solutions. This has been cut/pasted from that question into
>   this answer for clarity, but this answer does not stand-alone without
>   the insight provided in [**telcoM**'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418180/265441).

## Solution:

> I have made the following change according to **telcoM**'s suggestion below.

#### Created `/etc/google-dns-resolv.conf` with the contents:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

#### Added `resolv-file=/etc/google-dns-resolv.conf` to */etc/dnsmasq.conf*

> After making the change and running `sudo service dnsmasq restart` the CPU still spiked, but now `rsyslogd` entered into the mix of offenders. It settled down after about a minute, but I no longer saw `127.0.1.1` in `journalctl -f`.
>
> **Update:** After ~10 minutes, the CPU has spiked again:

[image]

> **Update #2:** Thanks to **telcoM**'s excellent little DNS crash-course below and skepticism over where `127.0.0.53` was coming from, I dug in a bit (see my comments on his answer) and discovered it was coming from **/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf**, which had the contents `nameserver 127.0.0.53`. I decided to update the contents to `nameserver 127.0.0.1`. Now, the only IP address I see output from `journalctl -f` is `127.0.0.1` and have not experienced a CPU spike since (going on ~10 mins now; which is at least as long as any period of rest my CPU has enjoyed prior)!
>
> **[SOLVED] Update #3:** Using `127.0.0.1` in **/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf** was foolish. It totally killed my DNS resolution (it appeared to work at first because I was only accessing cached DNSes). After switching to use Google nameservers (`8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4`) DNS resolution works again, my wildcard domains continue to work, and I am not experiencing CPU spikes. I'm going to see how this behaves for about an hour as I execute my typical day-to-day activities and update again accordingly; hopefully with a **SOLVED**!
>
> **Update #4:** This appears to be solved now by following the steps in **Update #3**. Thank you **telcoM** for all of the excellent detail that steered me in the right direction. Bounty will be awarded when available in 15 hours.